# Replacing HDD with SSD and DVD drive with HDD

Tags: hard-drive

HP Pavilion 15-ab05tx is my laptop model. I want to use SSD on the HDD portion and also replacing DVD drive with HDD. But a laptop mechanic told me that this may cause motherboard problem or others hardware problem. I'm not sure about this and have poor knowledge about hardware. But I want this if it's safe for my laptop. So,   which will be better in this case?

Comment: I see no reason why this would be unsafe. It is done all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see is that the DVD drive is 9 mm, while your hard disk is 9.5 mm
([manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05228250)).

While there are specialize HDD Caddies for DVD 9 mm replacement, such as
[this random one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PGNKYPX),
you need to carefully measure the real size taken up by the HDD,
in view of fitting within the caddy that you choose,
as everything might not fit in.

Some disk acrobatics will be needed, as you will not be able to boot from the HDD.
You will need to migrate the HDD to the SSD, so there will be the question of
disk capacity, whether the HDD will fit into the SSD.
Otherwise, you will need to re-install Windows on the SSD, but there shouldn't
be any Windows activation problems.

Answer (score 0):

What age is the computer?

I took a Lenovo M73 with up to date BIOS and firmware, backed up the hard drive, replaced it with a Samsung EVO 2TB SSD drive, used the Lenovo USB Recovery USB Key to install the operating system again and it is working just fine. I did this at the beginning of this year.

So as long as your drivers are up to date and HP supports the SSD drive, it should work fine

Comment: Thank you.
I had bought this in February 2016.

Answer (score -1):

This shouldn't be an issue, I have no idea why he would have told you that. I have done that exact upgrade in the past. As long as you have a HDD drive caddy in your DVD drive slot I can't imagine an issue with that setup.